# SSMTP ERROR : CANNOT OPEN SMTP.GMAIL.COM:587

Tags: centos, ssmtp

I've installed ssmtp on Centos 6 and configured it, here is my ssmtp.conf file contain :

```
root=xxx@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmail.com
hostname=xxx@gmail.com
UseTLS=Yes
UseSTARTTLS=Yes
AuthUser=xxx@gmail.com
AuthPass=Mail00Test
FromLineOverride=YES
TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

When sending mails, this error displays :

```
CANNOT OPEN SMTP.GMAIL.COM:587
```

Answer (score 4):

I am giving you few hints. Think those will solve your issue.

- 1. Change the hostname, like

     `hostname=localhost`
- 2. Go the below link and click `Turn on`
     https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- 3. Check the file TLS_CA_FILE exits or not.

Then try to send mail.